# Issue with UnauthorizedAccessException was Unhandled Error

Tags: c#

I keep getting the error for UnauthorizedAccessException and I am wondering if there is a way around this.

Here is the chunk of code where the error comes from. If someone could help me with this it would be very much appreciated.

```
public List<String> GetConnections()
    {
        dynamic everyConnection = null;
        dynamic connectionProp = null;

        List<string> connections = new List<string>();
        everyConnections = netSharingManager.EnumEveryConnection; // <<< UnathorizedAccessException
        foreach (dynamic connection in everyConnections)
        {
            everyConnection = netSharingManager.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection(connection);
            connectionProp = netSharingManager.NetConnectionProps(connection);
            connections.Add(connectionProp.Name);
        }

        return connections;
    }
```

Comment: What is `netSharingManager`?

Comment: It is a variable. for a virtual WiFi. didnt want to post almost 200 lines.

Comment: Having your current code, it is absolutely impossible to diagnose a error. This code does nothing that makes this error happen - the error certainly comes from another code.

Comment: then why do the error point at this line only? i can take a screen and show you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator